# How to exclude multiple subdirectories (same directory name) when using find command to delete files older than 30 days in a batch file?

Tags: linux, find, command

Given the below linux directory structure, how would I skip each excluded directory, (/assess), to remove files older than 30 days for the rest of the entire directory structure?

Thanks for your assistance...

```
/mnt/nfsmountpoint/location1/appliance1
/assess
/discover
/bkup
/mnt/nfsmountpoint/location1/appliance2
/assess
/discover
/bkup
etc...
```

I cobbled together an answer and proofs:: (my asterisks * are not showing sorry)

Run from the /mnt/nfsmountpoint/ directory.

find ./*/* -not -path "*/assess/*" -type f -mtime +30 -delete

validate::
Does it skip the directory?:
find ./*/* -not -path "*/assess/*" -type f -mtime +30 -ls|more

Verify no current month (January 2021) files included?:

find ./*/* -not -path "*/assess/*" -type f -mtime +30 -ls|grep Jan

How much space is made free?:

find ./*/* -not -path "*/assess/*" -type f -mtime +30 -print0 | du --files0-from=- hc | tail -n1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find /path/to/dir -mtime +30 -type f -not -name "*assess*" -delete
```

Find files (-type f) in /path/to/dir as well as children directories. Specify only files that have been modified more than 30 days ago (-mtime +30) and do not include files that contain "assess" (-not -name "*assess*")

Comment: Thanks - I had already cobbled together a similar resolution see newly edited problem...